# Why a DSB SY is required after updating ARM gic ICC_PMR register?

Tags: arm64, memory-barriers

In the linux kernel, updating SYS_ICC_PMR_EL1 is followed with a DSB SY if ICC_CTLR_EL1.PMHE == 0b1.

```
./arch/arm64/include/asm/irqflags.h:
45              write_sysreg_s(GIC_PRIO_IRQON, SYS_ICC_PMR_EL1);
   0xffff80008069ff90 <+156>:   mov     x0, #0xe0                       // #224
   0xffff80008069ff94 <+160>:   msr     s3_0_c4_c6_0, x0

46              pmr_sync();
   0xffff80008069ff98 <+164>:   dsb     sy
```

The explanation in commit msg is:

> When Priority Mask Hint Enable (PMHE) == 0b1, the GIC may use the PMR
> value to determine whether to signal an IRQ to a PE, and consequently
> after a change to the PMR value, a DSB SY may be required to ensure
> that interrupts are signalled to a CPU in finite time.

But DSB is a memory barrier, why it's required for updating a system register here? since it's not a mem op. And how can it "ensure that interrupts are signalled to a CPU in finite time"?

Comment: Isn't `dsb sy` different from `dmb sy`, blocking even more than just memory reordering?  I don't know what exactly the important thing is to ensure, or what earlier ops `dsb` waits for before which later ops, though.

Comment: (A simple memory barrier e.g. to implement `std::atomic_thread_fence(sec_cst)` is just `dmb ish`)

Comment: @PeterCordes  DSB esures no any instruction in program order after this instruction executes until DSB completes, while DMB only prevents re-order of memory accesse ops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DSB` is much more than just a memory barrier.  ARMv8 uses it as kind of a "synchronize everything" hammer.  The Architecture Reference Manual says:

> In addition, no instruction that appears in program order after the
> DSB instruction can alter any state of the system or perform any part
> of its functionality until the DSB completes other than:
>
> - Being
>   fetched from memory and decoded.
> - Reading the general-purpose, SIMD
>   and floating-point, SVE vector or predicate, Special-purpose, or
>   System registers that are directly or indirectly read without causing
>   side-effects.
> - If FEAT_ETS is not implemented, having any virtual
>   addresses of loads and stores translated.

There are a number of other system-type instructions with text like "guaranteed to be complete after a DSB".  For instance, DSB waits for all in-flight cache maintenance instructions to complete.

In particular, DSB is defined to have certain effects with respect to the interrupt controller.  This is documented in the [ARM Generic Interrupt Controller spec](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0069/latest/), section 12.1.6 (in issue H).

> Architectural execution of a DSB instruction guarantees that
>
> — The last
> value written to `ICC_PMR_EL1` or `GICC_PMR` is observed by the associated
> Redistributor. PMR values are only observable by the Redistributor
> when `ICC_CTLR_ELx.PMHE==1`, and observation by the Redistributor does
> not affect masking of interrupts within the CPU interface.
>
> — The last
> value written to `ICC_SGI0R_EL1` or `ICC_SGI1R_EL1` is observed by the
> associated Redistributor.
>
> [... and many more similar statements ...]

Comment: hm, I know these. But does updating SYS_ICC_PMR_EL1 regiter relate to these? Why it can "ensure that interrupts are signalled to a CPU in finite time"?

Comment: And in the chapter <Synchronization requirements for AArch64 System registers> of ARM documents, writing system registers requires an ISB sometimes but not a DSB.

Comment: @ChangbinDu: See 12.1.6 of the [Generic Interrupt Controller spec](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0069/latest/) which explains how DSB is needed in thsi setting.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect that writing these GIC registers goes through the store buffer so a DSB is required to drain it?

Comment: I know now. Updating the ICC_PMR_EL1 register needs to be observed by the redistributed which is an external component.

Comment: @ChangbinDu: I don't think it has anything to do with the store buffer.  Rather, it's just that DSB is a long microcode subroutine that does many different things, and one of them is to update the status of the external interrupt controller.